# QTableWidget validation number range

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I implement input validation in each cells? I want the input to be integers that fall within the range of 0 and 100

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set a QIntValidator to the editor created by the delegate:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
            validator = QtGui.QIntValidator(0, 100, editor)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
        return editor


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 4)
    table_widget.resize(640, 480)
    table_widget.show()

    delegate = Delegate()
    table_widget.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    app.exec_()
```

Another option is to use a QSpinBox as an editor that already has a validator.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent, minimum=0, maximum=100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 4)
    table_widget.resize(640, 480)
    table_widget.show()

    delegate = Delegate()
    table_widget.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    app.exec_()
```